# Laravel , save with new line between two textboxes

Tags: laravel, controller

```
public function store(Request $request, $id)
{
    $newEntry = new PaperPage();
        $newEntry->page1 = $request->input('textbox1') .'HERE'.$request->input('textbox2');        
        $newEntry->save();
}
```

**i just need a new line code between the textboxes, ineed it to place on the HERE**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can contact the `\n` at location of `HERE`
eg:

```
$newEntry->page1 = $request->input('textbox1') .'\n'.$request->input('textbox2');
```